# How to reload 'appsettings.json' upon change in a dotnet core 3 console app

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, reload

I'm trying to set up a console application to reload the 'appsettings.json' but I can't get it to react to a change of the file.

I've set up the main like so:

```
private static void Main ()
    {
        configuration = LoadConfiguration ();

        var services = ConfigureServices ();

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider ();

        serviceProvider.GetService<ConsoleApp> ().Run ();
    }

    private static IConfiguration LoadConfiguration ()
        => new ConfigurationBuilder ().SetBasePath (GetApplicationDirectory ())
                                      .AddJsonFile (_APP_SETTING_FILE_NAME, optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                                      .Build ();

    private static IServiceCollection ConfigureServices ()
    {
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection ();

        configuration.Bind (new AppSettings ()); // binds the 'appsettings.json' to the class

        services.AddSingleton (configuration);
        services.AddTransient<ConsoleApp> ();

        services.AddOptions<AppSettings> ();  // adds the IOption<T> and IOptionMonitor<T>

        // here I'm trying to follow a post from Dino Esposito [https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/asp-net-core-3-0-configuration-factsheet/][1] but services.Configure<AppSettings>() does not compile
        // the failure could be here? :-(
        services.Configure<AppSettings> (opt => opt.Default = configuration["Default"]);

        return services;
    }
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm doing something wrong here in the configuration of the DI but I cannot figure out what.

The console app is quite simple and should register the cahgne but does not, anyway here it is

```
public class ConsoleApp
{
    public AppSettings AppSettings { get; }

    public ConsoleApp (IOptionsMonitor<AppSettings> appSettingsOptionsMonitor)
    {
        AppSettings = appSettingsOptionsMonitor.CurrentValue;

        appSettingsOptionsMonitor.OnChange ((arg1, arg2) => Console.WriteLine ($"\t ---> AppSettings changed to '{arg1.Default}' - '{arg2}'"));

        Console.WriteLine ($"ctor - appsettings current value: '{AppSettings.Default}'.\n");
    }

    public void Run ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ($"\tCurrent value: '{AppSettings.Default}' - waiting for change ...");

        while (AppSettings.Default != "Stop") { }

        Console.WriteLine ($"\t... has changed to '{AppSettings.Default}'.");
    }
}
```

The class AppSettings is:

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public string Default { get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreaciated!

T'X
Peter

Comment: I recently implemented something like this and it was an absolute pain. I could never get the various reloadOnChange methods I had seen documented work.The only way I was able to accomplish this was by writing to the file directly and then calling `ConfigureServices` again with a new ServiceCollection. I'm keen to follow this post to see what others recommend. There was some stuff related to this in .NET Framework that hasn't yet made it into .Net Core, if it ever will.

Comment: I will add the warning that many issues arose when I was implementing this, and the architects above me decided the feature would be too prone to fault to ever use practically. You would be much better off using your own configuration file, not appsettings. Errors with appsettings can cause your service to be in an inconsistent state or just crash entirely. Now we only use appsettings as a fallback/ default option if loading secondary configuration fails.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use the extension method [AddOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.optionsservicecollectionextensions.addoptions?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions_AddOptions__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_) to do this,
because it wasn't designed to work with file configuration provider.
To do this, you must use the extension methods in the class [OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.optionsconfigurationservicecollectionextensions?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

The key is in the [OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/7d9baaf617741d775578c8018729ac5b75734c69/src/Options/ConfigurationExtensions/src/OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L71) class and [OptionsMonitor](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/7d9baaf617741d775578c8018729ac5b75734c69/src/Options/Options/src/OptionsMonitor.cs#L34) class.
You can see in the OptionsMonitor class's constructor, it will take all the IOptionsChangeTokenSource instances registered in service container, which were registered by OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions.Configure method.The IOptionsChangeTokenSource instance reloads the options when the under configuration file changed.

As a comparison, you can see in the [AddOptions](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/7d9baaf617741d775578c8018729ac5b75734c69/src/Options/Options/src/OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L221) method, it doesn't register an IOptionsChangeTokenSource instance.